# Swift: Will XCTest modify state? And what is the convention of testing functions that could return optional values?

Tags: swift, testing, xctest

Two questions here:

1. Will the `XCTAssertEqual` function and other assert functions modify the state of the program? By this I mean, e.g., will something like

   ```
   XCTAssertEqual(queue.dequeue(), ..., ...)
   ```

   change the state of the queue? Does Swift (or probably programming languages in general) revert the state of the queue to that before the execution of this statement?
2. What would be a recommended way of writing tests for functions that could return an optional value? For example, I have a method `dequeue`, as part of the Queue class, that could return a value, or `nil` if the queue is empty.

   Should I do (the idea here is to unwrap the optional value):

   ```
   XCTAssertEqual(queue.dequeue()!, ..., ...)
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   if let item = queue.dequeue() {
       XCTAssertEqual(item, ..., ...)
   }
   ```

   Or probably other ways of testing.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, if you call a method that changes the state of an object/variable, then calling the `XCTAssert...` with this function as one of the parameters macro will result in the state-changing method getting called, resulting the concomitant state changes. No, there is nothing here that would revert the state.

   Conventionally, if state changes were involved, many of us would assign the result to a variable, and then test that variable (and possibly the state change, too):

   ```
   let returnCode = object.changeState()
   XCTAssertEqual(returnCode, ...)
   XCTAssertEqual(object.someStateProperty, ...)
   ```

   This is a stylistic matter when dealing with unit tests, but it is critical when using macros like `NSAssert` (because those are conditionally compiled depending upon build configuration and you don't want object states changing depending upon the build).
2. Regarding the optionals, either forced unwrapping or optional binding is permissible, though, as always, the latter is safer if `nil` value is possible. Furthermore, if `nil` is acceptable value, you might need to perform additional tests for the various permutations (e.g. `XCTAssertNil` and `XCTAssertNotNil`).

   It depends entirely upon what precisely you're trying to test.